# UIImageView in front of UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am making iPad photo slide show app. I let the user open up their photo albums using UIPopoverController. When a user selects an image I would like to show them a message saying that the photo was added/selected. But the problem I have is that it keeps showing up behind the uipopover. How can I display it on top of the uipopover? See screenshot

[image]

Don't worry the image fades away after a sec.

Here is the code that I am using

```
-(IBAction)selectExitingPicture
{
    //Specially for fing iPAD
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 300.0) 
                             inView:self.view
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                           animated:YES];

    photoAddedImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 250, 300, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:photoAddedImgView];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

....

UIImage *photoAddedImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button_photo_added" ofType:@"png"]];

        [self.photoAddedImgView setImage:photoAddedImg];

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `photoAddedImgView` to the application's window instead of `self.view`?

Comment: You could present `photoAddedImgView` inside `contentViewController` of `UIPopoverViewcontroller` or you could move popover a bit lower (you can present it like `presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(200.0, 450.0, 1.0, 1.0)`

Comment: I tried window.view instead of self.view and that didn't do anything either

Answer (score 2):

Try using `insertSubview:atIndex:` or `insertSubview:aboveSubview` instead of an `addSubView` when you display your status message.

**EDIT:**

I investigated a bit more in the iOS HIG, and look what I've found:

> "Don’t display a modal view on top of a popover. Except for an alert,
>   nothing should display on top of a popover."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW40

So in fact, that might be normal that you're not able to do this. And even if it's possible, you should re-think what you want to do, since it's really not recommended according to the HIG.

Comment: nope, didn't do anything. I tried [self.view insertSubview:photoAddedImgView atIndex:5]; ... atIndex from 1-10 and it still showed my image behind the popover

Comment: It maybe frowned upon but there are couple of app already out there in app store that show a pop-up image ontop of the pop-over. Look at flickIt or Yahoo Flickr apps. They both do it. Now question is how are they doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Add your image as subview to UIWindow. It won't autorotate, but it will be displayed on top of everything.